# polymorphic function on existential type

Tags: haskell, existential-type

So say I have a class:

```
class C a where
  reduce :: a -> Int
```

Now I want to pack it up in a data type:

```
data Signal = forall a. (C a) => Signal [(Double, a)]
```

Thanks to the existential quantification, I can call C methods on Signals, but Signals don't expose a type parameter:

```
reduceSig :: Signal -> [(Double, Int)]
reduceSig (Signal sig) = map (second reduce) sig
```

Now since C has a number of methods my natural next step is to pull out the 'reduce' function so I can substitute any method:

```
mapsig :: (C a) => (a -> a) -> Signal -> Signal
mapsig f (Signal sig) = Signal (map (second f) sig)
```

Type error!  Could not deduce (a1 ~ a).  On further thought, I think what it's saying is that 'f' is a function on some instance of C, but I can't guarantee it's the *same* instance of C as in the Signals, because the type parameters are concealed!  I wanted it, I got it.

So does this mean it's impossible to generalize reduceSig?  I can live with this, but I'm so used to freely factoring out functions in haskell it feels strange to be obliged to write the boilerplate.  On the other hand, I can't think of any way to express that a type is equal to the type inside of Signal, short of giving Signal a type parameter.

Comment: By the way, unless `C` contains more than you have here, your `Signal` type is equivalent to `data Signal = Signal [(Double, Int)]`! So there's no advantage to using an existential type here, unless this is a simplified problem (see also: [1](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), [2](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#I.27m_making_an_RPG._Should_I_define_a_type_for_each_kind_of_monster.2C_and_a_type_class_for_them.3F), although the situations they address aren't completely analogous).

Comment: Yeah, C has a bunch of methods, I was just trying to simplify for the example.  But as you point out, simplify too much and the whole rationale goes away :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need to express is that `f`, like `reduce` used in `reduceSig`, can be applied to *any* type that is an instance of `C`, as opposed to the current type, where `f` works on a single type that is an instance of `C`. This can be done like so:

```
mapsig :: (forall a. (C a) => a -> a) -> Signal -> Signal
mapsig f (Signal sig) = Signal (map (second f) sig)
```

You'll need the `RankNTypes` extension, as you often do when using existential types; note that the *implementation* of `mapsig` is the same, the type has just been generalised.

Basically, with this type, `mapsig` gets to decide which *a* the function is called on; with your previous type, the *caller* of `mapsig` gets to decide that, which doesn't work, because only `mapsig` knows the correct *a*, i.e. the one inside the `Signal`.

However, `mapsig reduce` does not work, for the obvious reason that `reduce :: (C a) => a -> Int`, and you don't know that *a* is Int! You need to give `mapsig` a more general type (with the same implementation):

```
mapsig :: (C b) => (forall a. (C a) => a -> b) -> Signal -> Signal
```

i.e., `f` is a function taking *any* type that is an instance of `C`, and producing a type that is an instance of `C` (that type is fixed at the time of the `mapsig` call and chosen by the caller; i.e. while the value `mapsig f` can be called on any Signal, it will always produce a Signal with the same *a* as a result (not that you can inspect this from outside).)

Existentials and rank-N types are very tricky indeed, so this might take a bit of time to digest. :)

---

As an addendum, it's worth pointing out that if all the functions in `C` look like `a -> r` for some r, then you would be better off creating a *record* instead, i.e. turning

```
class C a where
  reduce :: a -> Int
  foo :: a -> (String, Double)
  bar :: a -> ByteString -> Magic

data Signal = forall a. (C a) => Signal [(Double, a)]

mapsig :: (C b) => (forall a. (C a) => a -> b) -> Signal -> Signal
```

into

```
data C = C
  { reduce :: Int
  , foo :: (String, Double)
  , bar :: ByteString -> Magic
  }

data Signal = Signal [(Double, C)]

mapsig :: (C -> C) -> Signal -> Signal
```

These two Signal types are actually equivalent! The benefits of the former solution only appear when you have other data types that use `C` *without* existentially quantifying it, so that you can have code that uses special knowledge and operations of the specific instance of `C` it's using. If your primary use-cases of this class are through existential quantification, you probably don't want it in the first place. But I don't know what your program looks like :)

Comment: Aha, I thought it would involve RankNTypes somehow, but I didn't know that it would select a type for 'a' to agree with the type hidden inside Signal.  That's pretty cool.  Actually, it turns out I slightly misstated my problem, 'C a' has various 'a->a' functions, and those are happy with the first mapsig.  You're right, the second is a little magical seeming and I'll have to put some more thought into that one.  Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: Well, it can pick any *a* it wants, and it *has* to pick a single given *a* it knows nothing about — not a difficult choice for a type-checker :) I'm glad you found it enlightening.

Comment: (Note that you can rephrase `a -> a` functions inside the `C` typeclass as `C` fields of a `C` data type. I don't know your design, of course; just throwing that out there.)

Comment: Right, I agree about the record, and I usually prefer records to classes.  But here's the real class declaration: `class Scale d where transpose_chromatic :: Int -> d -> d; transpose_diatonic :: Int -> d -> d; reduce :: Degree d -> Frequency`.  Given that, I could put the functions in a record, but I'd still need a polymorphic 'd' since notes of different scales will require different amounts of data to represent them.  I suppose the functions could all be pre-partially-applied to the appropriate data... hmm, I'll have to think more on it.

Comment: Well, `transpose_chromatic` and `transpose_diatonic` are easily represented as `Int -> ScaleValue` fields (where the data type is `ScaleValue`), but you'd have to change the definition of `Degree`. I *think* it should be fairly easy, assuming `Degree` isn't a type family, but if you don't use this class solely through existential quantification, then I agree it probably isn't worth it. It's another question entirely, anyway :) Good luck with your design!

Comment: Although, I note that `Int -> ScaleValue` might be best represented as `[ScaleValue]` or `Stream ScaleValue`.

Comment: Ah, I suppose you mean pre-apply transpose to [1..] and let laziness do its thing.  Assuming that transpositions are small numbers, I can see how this is mostly equivalent.  Of course, I'd need two, one for positive and one for negative.  I wonder what other reasons there are to prefer one over the other?

Comment: I think I would probably stick with the function representation, unless you might want to e.g. fold over a prefix of the list. (Although I'd use Integer instead of Int.) But it's something to think about.

Comment: I was wracking my brain on how to implement polymorphic devices for a Z80 simulator (partition memory into regions, memory mapped devices have both state and State manipulation functions.) The record approach worked very nicely.